# How to filter ECG signal using Armadillo?

Tags: c++, qt, armadillo

How to filter ECG signal using Armadillo in C++ Qt?

I get ECG Data:

```
        data = frame.mid(1, 19);
        QList<QByteArray> splitData = data.split(',');
        QString ekgString(splitData[0]);
        double EkgValue = ekgString.toDouble();
```

Best

Comment: You will have to store all the values in an armadillo array, for example by using a for loop over all your data.

Comment: What filtering do you want to do? High pass, low pass, band pass, averaging? More detail is needed.

Comment: Indifferently, it can be Hight pass or low pass for example